# Why is the tab not functioning in my winforms?

Tags: tabs

I'm trying to use tab to move between the textbox in my winforms application, I have enabled the tabstop property and have set the taborder in view menu but still when I use tab I just hear a sound and it doesn't move to the next textbox, why is this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you set `KeyPreview` to true on your Form?

If so, set it to false.